# Extra margins I cannot remove during Grid Experiments

Tags: html, css

I am practicing with Grid in CSS and trying to move around elements to understand better the flow. I do not understand why there are margins around `body` and `html`. There is an extra 10px above "Element 3" and "Element 1"'s row is 20px even if it is not allocated space for it. So, why "Element 1" is still shown, while all the `margins` are equal to 0? How to remove the 20px above Element 3?

```css
 *{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-width:0px;
 }

.container {
    margin: 20px;
    display: grid;
    height: 240px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header header header" 
                         "main main main main"
                         "footer footer footer footer";
}

.el1 {
    background: rgba(255, 154, 72, 0.5);
    margin: 0;
}

.el2 {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 10;
    grid-area: main;
    margin: 0;
}

.el3 {
    background: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5);
    grid-area: header;
    margin: 0;
 }

.el4 {
    background: rgba(0, 4, 255, 0.5);
    grid-area: footer;
    margin: -20;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CSS Course</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="el1">Element 1</div>
        <div class="el2">Element 2</div>
        <div class="el3">Element 3</div>
        <div class="el4">Element 4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are adding margin to the container

Comment: element1 is showing because it's *there*. All the elements are shown by default unless you specify the opposite (display:none, visibility, etc)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for explaining. So are elements able to overwrite default settings even if any `margin` are set to 0?

Comment: each element has its own margin, you applied 20px to the container so it's has margin. The child has no role here even if you specify marign:0 inside them (it applies to only them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin above Element 3 is from your container:

```
.container {
    margin: 20px;
```

Element 1 is shown because it is in the grid container. `grid-template-areas` only defines in which grid areas the item should be. Without that definition it is shown only in one grid area...